# How to change the content in a datagrid or listview using MVVM

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a MainWindowViewModel (DataContext) which exposes different ObservableCollections<> (viewmodels of the poco objects with INotifyProperty.... ).After selecting a value from a combobox i want to click a load button which then displays the desired data in a datagrid or listview. Problem is, that in the xaml code i can only define the itemssource and column specific definitions for one collection. So how can i change the data that is displayed in way that is compliant with MVVM. Are there any best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create in your ViewModel a property that exposes an `IEnumerable`. Bind the DataGrids `ItemsSource` to that property. You can set then the property from inside the ViewModel to any of your collections and then the data will change.
Please note that you should specify two-way binding and that your property must support some change-notification (support `INotifyPropertyChanged` or be a `DependencyProperty`).

Comment: It seems to work know. I implemented an IEnumerable property and the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in my MainWindowViewModel. I am now able to display every table from my database in the datagrid.